# Virtual Wifi on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, ieee802.1x

Sorry if this is a very dumb question. I have installed the virtualWIFI msi on vista. I assumed that would simply just allow selecting more than one wifi connection with my single card however I don't get much new options.

Any help on how to get this running on vista is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This software if simply Deprecated... It has been release in 2005 by Microsoft and is not longer supported by them for a while right now.

Over all, it was made for Windows XP, so no surprise here if it doesn't work with the new wireless stack that Vista introduced...

Comment: is there a new equivalent for this in vista?

Answer (score 0):

There is an intel driver for virtual wifi in Windows 7 which allows to connect to two wifi network at the same time.